# Adding imageView having video frames to scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am working on an application in which I am **extracting video frames** and the frames are of `UIImage` object. And once the frames are extracted they are added to the `scrollview` by setting the images in `UIImageView`.

But the problem is that if the video got 60 frames I have to create 60 `ImageView` to store each frame and it is causing LIVE Bites of the app to 47 MB or more when i add more videos.

**So I need an alternative way by which image frames extracted can be added to the scroll view without allocating 60 ImageViews for 60 frames.**

To add frames to scroll view I am using following code.

```
for (i=0; i<[arrExtractedFrams count]; i++) 
{

            UIImageView *imgFrame=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[arrExtractedFrams objectAtIndex:i]];

            [imgFrame setFrame:CGRectMake(FramePosition, 0, thumbnail_width, self.frame.size.height)];

            [self addSubview:imgFrame];
            if (videoLength<=11) {
                FramePosition+=thumbnail_width;
            }
            else{
                FramePosition+=((self.superview.frame.size.height-TRIMMERS_WIDTH_TOTAL)/videoLength);
            }
 }
```

Comment: You can make circular scrollview and set image over it

Comment: Or a table view, or a collection view.